# Multiple imputation with firm R - options for including firm level fixed effects

Tags: r, panel-data, multiple-imputation

I have a rather large panel data (ca. 600 000 obs in ten years and 75 000 firms) that has some missing observations that need to be imputed. I have thus far managed to impute the missing values with Amelia package. However, when I tried to include the firm ID as the cross section variable, the model turned out to be computationally too demanding. Including that firm ID would be desirable as I want that the imputed values would reflect the heterogeneity among firms.

Do you think that including that ID variable is feasible after all? If so, is Amelia good for the job or should I also try some other package?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was feasible after all. Removing argument intercs = T was enough to make it run. That however came with a cost of omitting trends specific to cross sectional units.